# Mid point of cross correlate

Tags: python, scipy, cross-correlation

I have two dataset `(x1,y1)` and `(x2,y2)`, where the first dataset is longer than the second one, which means that `x1[0]<x2[0]` and `x1[-1]>x2[0]`. But the length the first data set is longer to each side is not the same in general.

I cross correlate with scipy using

```
ycorr = scipy.correlate(y1,y2,mode='valid')
xcorr = np.linspace( 0,len(ycorr)-1,len(ycorr) )
```

My question is how I find the midpoint of the cross correlation = the one point where `ycorr` is calculated if the two dataset has the same length and `mode='valid'`.
So the midpoint is NOT xcorr[len(xcorr)/2].

It may be hard to understand my question so please ask if something is not clear.

**EDIT**

To find the mid point we have to see at the length at the end points. So how much longer is `x1` than `x2` at the end.

The mid point is given by

```
for i in xrange( len(x1)-1 ):
    if x1[i]<x2[-1] and x1[i+1]>x2[-1]:
        I = i
        break

mid_point = (len(y1[I:-1])+len(y1[I+1:-1]))/2
```

Comment: Questions: 1/ "where the first dataset is longer than the first one": you mean 'second one', right? 2/ you correlate y1 & y2; yet in the first paragraph you  compare x1 and x2? 3/ I'm not overly familiar with correlate(), but with mode='valid', it seems to return values only where y1 and y2 overlap; but that still wouldn't return a single point ("the one point"). Which one point? At best guess, you want a point in x1 or x2 that corresponds to the midpoint of your output correlation, assuming y1 matches x1 in length, and ditto for y2 and x2. Is that correct?

Comment: 1: Yes. I have updated the post.
2: I correlate the y1 and y2, because that is how one use to do a correlation. 
3: That is right. The mode='valid' return points where the first and second data set overlap. The single point I am talking about will be the point if the cross correlation was calculated and the two data sets had the same length (len(x1)=len(x2)).
That is correct. x1 and y1 has same lengths (ditto for x2 and y2).

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://www.tramy.us/numpybook.pdf), when you correlate `y1` (length `N+1`) and `y2` (length `M+1`, with `M<=N`) in `'valid'` mode, the middle `N-M+1=(N+1)-(M+1)+1` output values are returned, starting at `M`  [In `'full'` mode, values are returned from `0` to `N+M`, in `'same'` mode  the `N` middle values are returned starting at `(M-1)/2`]

So, you should have `len(ycorr) = len(y1)-len(y2)+1` (`=1` if the two vectors have the same size)

You also have `ycorr[i] = np.correlate(y1[i:len(y2)+i], y2, "valid")` for all `i` in `range(len(ycorr))`

Comment: Yes I have `len(ycorr)=len(y1)-len(y2)+1` but that does not give me the mid point I am looking for.

Comment: Doesn't your midpoint depends on where you start with your `y1` (cf edit)?

Comment: Yes exactly! It is so hard to explain properly. My mid point depends on where the y2 starts relative to y1.

Comment: In what respect the formula I gave in the edit doesn't help you?

Comment: Well, it does not give me the mid point. Or I do not see what the midpoint is to be more precise.

Comment: Could you give an actual example, then? Assuming that `y1` has size 50, `y2` size 30, and that both start at the same time, where is your midpoint? If now `y2` starts at the same time as `y1[10]`, where is your midpoint?

Comment: It should be at respectively index `0` and `10` but that does not work. I think that the problem can be, that the distance between two points `x1[i]` and `x1[i+1]` is not constant. Actually the distance grows linearly.

Comment: Ah. You should put this information in your question, then. Does the progression from one index to the next the same in `x1` and `x2`?

Comment: Yes the progression is the same in `x1` and `x2` and from index to the next index.

Comment: It finally works! I seems that the start points does not matter at all in the cross correlation. You have to check the end points. See the original question for the solution.
Thank you for your time. You made me thinking in the right way.